# eliminar LI a una UL

Tags: javascript, html

```js
/**
         * Funcion que añade un <li> dentro del <ul>
         */
 function add_li()
 {
     var nuevoLi=document.getElementById("nuevo_li").value;
     if(nuevoLi.length>0)
     {
         if(find_li(nuevoLi))
         {
             var li=document.createElement('li');
             li.id=nuevoLi;
             li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X</span>"+ " " +nuevoLi;
             document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").appendChild(li);
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

 /**
  * Funcion que busca si existe ya el <li> dentrol del <ul>
  * Devuelve true si no existe.
  */
 function find_li(contenido)
 {
     var el = document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").getElementsByTagName("li");
     for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
     {
         if(el[i].innerHTML==contenido)
             return false;
     }
     return true;
 }

 /**
  * Funcion para eliminar los elementos
  * Tiene que recibir el elemento pulsado
  */
 function eliminar(elemento)
 {
     var id=elemento.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
     node=document.getElementById(id);
     node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
 }

 function eliminarPrimero(){

 }

 function eliminarUltimo(){
  let x = document.querySelector('li');
  let cantidad = x.length;
  x = x.eq(cantidad - 1);
  x.remove();
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Enunciado 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enunciado 2</h1>
        <h1>Añadir y eliminar elementos li de una lista desordenada ul con javascript</h1>
        <p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nuevo_li">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return add_li()" value="añadir">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return eliminarPrimero()" value="eliminar primero">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return eliminarUltimo()" value="eliminar ultimo">
            </form>
        </p>
        <ul id="listaDesordenada">
            <li id="li_inicial">Linea 1</li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                let li = document.getElementById("li_inicial")
                li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X Linea 1</span>"+ " ";
            </script>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./enunciado_2.js"></script>
</html>
```

Tengo este código HTML y simplemente quiero que se pueda borrar el ultimo LI o el primer LI según el botón que se pulse mediante JavaScript. El código que tengo no me funciona.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Hola revise este código le hice algunos cambios para que funcione:

```js
/**
         * Funcion que añade un <li> dentro del <ul>
         */
 function add_li()
 {
     var nuevoLi=document.getElementById("nuevo_li").value;
     if(nuevoLi.length>0)
     {
         if(find_li(nuevoLi))
         {
             var li=document.createElement('li');
             li.id=nuevoLi;
             li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X</span>"+ " " +nuevoLi;
             document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").appendChild(li);
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

 /**
  * Funcion que busca si existe ya el <li> dentrol del <ul>
  * Devuelve true si no existe.
  */
 function find_li(contenido)
 {
     var el = document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").getElementsByTagName("li");
     for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
     {
         if(el[i].innerHTML==contenido)
             return false;
     }
     return true;
 }

 /**
  * Funcion para eliminar los elementos
  * Tiene que recibir el elemento pulsado
  */
 function eliminar(elemento)
 {
     var id=elemento.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
     node=document.getElementById(id);
     node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
 }

 function eliminarPrimero(){
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let cantidad = x.length;
  if (cantidad > 0){
   x = x[0];
   x.remove();
  }
 
  return false;
 }

 function eliminarUltimo(){
  let x = document.querySelectorAll('li');
  let cantidad = x.length;
  if (cantidad > 0){
    x = x[cantidad - 1];
    x.remove();
  }
  
  return false;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Enunciado 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enunciado 2</h1>
        <h1>Añadir y eliminar elementos li de una lista desordenada ul con javascript</h1>
        <p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nuevo_li">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return add_li()" value="añadir">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return eliminarPrimero()" value="eliminar primero">
                <br><input type="submit" onclick="return eliminarUltimo()" value="eliminar ultimo">
            </form>
        </p>
        <ul id="listaDesordenada">
            <li id="li_inicial">Linea 1</li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                let li = document.getElementById("li_inicial")
                li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X Linea 1</span>"+ " ";
            </script>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./enunciado_2.js"></script>
</html>
```

En la función eliminar último tiene q usar `querySelectorAll` para obtener todos los `li` después es acceder a la última posición o la primara si quiere eliminar el primero, además le agregué in *if* para comprobar que al menos exista un `li`, si no existe ninguno no tenemos nada que eliminar Saludos

Answer (score 1):

ya tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta ya lo resolvi usando removeChild y childrenlenght, tambien tenias un error y es que tenias inputs de tipo submit es por eso que la pagina se pone en blanco usa unos de tipo button todo esta explicado en el codigo de abajo.

```js
function add_li()
 {
     var nuevoLi=document.getElementById("nuevo_li").value;
     if(nuevoLi.length>0)
     {
         if(find_li(nuevoLi))
         {
             var li=document.createElement('li');
             li.id=nuevoLi;
             li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X</span>"+ " " +nuevoLi;
             document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").appendChild(li);
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
 function find_li(contenido)
 {
     var el = document.getElementById("listaDesordenada").getElementsByTagName("li");
     for (var i=0; i<el.length; i++)
     {
         if(el[i].innerHTML==contenido)
             return false;
     }
     return true;
 }

 function eliminar(elemento)
 {
     var id=elemento.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
     node=document.getElementById(id);
     node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
 }

 function eliminarPrimero(){
  //obten el elemento padre de los elementoa li
  var padre = document.querySelector('#listaDesordenada');
  //obtenemos el primer hijo del elemento padre.
  var elemento1 = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
  //y removemos el primer elemento hijo del elemento padre
  padre.removeChild(elemento1);
 }

 function eliminarUltimo(){
  //obten el elemento padre de los elementoa li
  var padre = document.querySelector('#listaDesordenada');
  //sacamos la cantidad de elementos hijo.
  var ultimo = padre.children.length;
  //le restamos 1
  ultimo = ultimo - 1;
  //obtenemos el ultimo hijo del elemento padre.
  var eu = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[ultimo];
  //y removemos el ultimo elemento hijo del elemento padre
  padre.removeChild(eu);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Enunciado 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enunciado 2</h1>
        <h1>Añadir y eliminar elementos li de una lista desordenada ul con javascript</h1>
        <p>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="nuevo_li">
                <br><input type="button" onclick="return add_li()" value="añadir">
                <br><input type="button" onclick="return eliminarPrimero()" value="eliminar primero">
                <br><input type="button" onclick="return eliminarUltimo()" value="eliminar ultimo">
            </form>
        </p>
        <ul id="listaDesordenada">
            <li id="li_inicial">Linea 1</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // movi este elemento script abajo por que estorbaba dentro del ul, sigue funcionando.
                let li = document.getElementById("li_inicial")
                li.innerHTML="<span onclick='eliminar(this)'>X Linea 1</span>"+ " ";
            </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./enunciado_2.js"></script>
</html>
```